# EMI Noises - when controller is powered up

Tags: spi, noise, emc

I have one sensor which I need to interface with my controller using SPI communication. The manufacturer of the sensor tells that both controller and sensor should be on same PCB. When we asked manufacturer that if we can mount sensor and controller on different PCB and connect via cable. They told that it will work when connected via cable in a **noise and EMI** free environment.And they recommended to place both controller and sensor on same PCB.

My question is what activities can lead to noises generation when the controller is powered on?

Waiting for the reply.

Regards

Comment: It's called EMI - go look it up while you are "Waiting for the reply".

Comment: What does that mean? Sorry,  I didnt get you. EMI - electromagnetic interference

Comment: Two components on the same PCB sharing (usually) the same ground plane will normally be far less susceptible to EMI from external or local sources compared to components seperated by a wiring loom.

Comment: If that is the reason, can't we connect the ground of the sensor to the ground of the controller so that both have the same ground, when connected via cable? Wont this help?

Comment: Well, their grounds needs to be connected so that they function so that's a moot point. Cable connections are normally far more susceptible to EMI. Cables make great antennas. Having said that it wouldn't stop me but I have no idea how critical your connection is.